# elastic load balancer port redirection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

i configured an ELB for an ec2 instance such the load balancer receives data from http:80 send it to https:443 to instances. But when i entered ELB DNS url , it is not redirecting to https.

[image]

output of ELB is:
[image]

it is showing the output of port 80. can anyone please help to configure elb such that it redirects incoming port 80 traffic to port 443 to ec2 instacne.

Answer (score 1):

Load balancer used to send and receive traffic from different ports from the EC2 instances attached to that Load Balancer. You cannot setup any redirect using a Load Balancer. For redirects you have to set that up using the Web Server of your EC2 instance attached to that load balancer.

Also as per the https goes either you add a SSL certificate to the EC2 instance or the ELB. But that SSL certificate will be for the domain you are going to use for your application, and you do not own the domain "amazonaws.com" so your load balancer URL will never work for https. You have get a Domain and a SSL certificate for that domain upload that SSL certificate to ELB or the EC2 instance and then point the domain to the ELB by adding a C-Name. Then your domain will work for https ://www.domain.com if you have set everything correctly in the web server.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS. This is more than just a port "redirect", it is also a protocol change. To properly redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS you will need to configure your web server to do that.